# RandomizedSearchCV - worse accuracy than standard parameters

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am currently training a text classification model to infer product category (198 different ones) from product names. After evaluating a few models I have decided to stick with a Random Forest (reaching ~86% accuracy on the test set).

After going through randomized search (hyperparams grid and setup below), model accuracy surprisingly decreased.
I am not sure why this happens but it seems it is related to `min_samples_split` as it's the main change between the two parameter sets.

Attaching both default and parameters resulting from `RandomizedSearchCV()`. Also, I've been forced to remove `max_estimators` hyperparam as it was getting the command insanely long to compute.

```py
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start=1, stop=250, num=20)]
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num = 11)]
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
min_sample_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
bootstrap = [True, False]

param_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
              'max_features': max_features,
              'max_depth': max_depth,
              'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
              'min_samples_leaf': min_sample_leaf,
              'bootstrap': bootstrap}

rf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
k = model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

rf_acc_cv_rand = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator= rf,
                                    param_distributions=param_grid,
                                    n_iter=50,
                                    cv = k,
                                    verbose=10,
                                    random_state=42,
                                    n_jobs=-1)

rf_acc_cv_rand.fit(x_train_count, y_train)
```

Default values (accuracy ~86%)

```py
>>> randomforest_norandsearch.get_params()
{'bootstrap': True,
 'class_weight': None,
 'criterion': 'gini',
 'max_depth': None,
 'max_features': 'auto',
 'max_leaf_nodes': None,
 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.0,
 'min_impurity_split': None,
 'min_samples_leaf': 1,
 'min_samples_split': 2,
 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0,
 'n_estimators': 10,
 'n_jobs': None,
 'oob_score': False,
 'random_state': None,
 'verbose': 0,
 'warm_start': False}
```

After randomised search (accuracy ~74%)

```py
>>> randomforest_rand.best_params_
{'n_estimators': 40,
 'min_samples_split': 10,
 'min_samples_leaf': 1,
 'max_features': 'auto',
 'max_depth': 110,
 'bootstrap': False}
```

Comment: For some of your hyperparameters, you have chosen very strange values (e.g. a depth above 20...). What is the dimension of your data? How do you evaluate the final accuracy?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelM for your reply. I'm looking at 149153 observation spread across 198 different target categories. Accuracy evaluation is performed through `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score()`method.

Comment: @MichaelM, the default random forest allows full depth, so I doubt that's it.  I wonder if it's not the hyperparameters, but that the (current) default of 10 trees is allowing a lot of variance in the scores?  How did the cross-validation scores compare?

Comment: Good point @BenReiniger

Comment: @MichaelM, not sure how to grab cv scores for each iteration, total noob here. Anyway will try to throw `n_estimators` into the mix to see if going beyond default values brings any improvement.

Comment: The RandomizedSearchCV object has an attribute `cv_results_`; see the documentation. Normally more trees will just stabilize the results, so you wouldn't search over that (instead just pick it "large enough"); but here it might be a good way to test my hypothesis.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/andodet/f0d566a6ce50457de587745918f53dbf) you can find results when searching for `n_estimators` as well, the search happened to stabilise at 40 trees. Data is quite unbalanced, could `min_samples_split` and `min_samples_leaf` have a high impact on the scores? Also, inspecting my original model, its average tree depth is ~4231, quite far from the param grid I'm searching against. Hope this helps.

Comment: Randomized search is checking in your case 50 out of 7920 possible hyperparameter configurations (If I computed it well), i.e., 0.6% of the search space. It is very likely that in that 0.6% of search space have no "good" configuration.